# Services Internal Communication by RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I have two services:
Service A, User microservice which has a table for having users' personal information
Service B, Company microservice which has a table for companies information.

For example, I have a route: `api/v1/companies/list`, In this case, the request goes to service B and gets a list of all companies, each company has the user_id which shows this company has belonged to the user. in this request, I want to render the info of the company's user in the list, So I have to send a request to the route of service A like `api/v1/user/{user_id}`.
How can I handle this internal communication without data replication?
Can I use RabbitMQ?

Comment: from api/v1/companies/list API controller / resource you can call user service api/v1/user/{user_id} for each user_id. Calling for each user_id is not optimal, so you can try to create special GET endpoint for list of user_ids (api/v1/users) in user service. This way you call user service only once.  I would recommend to change api/v1/companies/list to api/v1/companies to comply with REST GET.